# ¿Como acomodar datos de consulta?

Tags: sql

Tengo una consulta que me devuelve los datos que quiero, pero para evitar utilizar tantos ciclos en la parte de programación para presentar la información de la forma en que quiero, me gustaría saber si existe alguna manera de re acomodar el siguiente resultado de una consulta sql:

[image: datos devueltos]

de la siguiente forma:

[image: como me gustaría que quedarán]

consulta que utilizo:

```
SELECT A.Apellidos, M.Materia, FORMAT(SUM(FORMAT((N.Nota_Obtenida * (T.Ponderacion / 100)), 2)), 2) AS promedio, ME.Mes
        FROM materia_grado MG 
        INNER JOIN grado G ON MG.Id_Grado = G.Id_Grado
        INNER JOIN materia M ON MG.Id_Materia = M.Id_Materia
        INNER JOIN tarea T ON T.Id_Materia_Grado = MG.Id_Materia_Grado
        INNER JOIN nota N ON T.Id_Tarea = N.Id_Tarea 
        INNER JOIN grado_seccion GS ON G.Id_Grado = GS.Id_Grado
        INNER JOIN seccion S ON S.Id_Seccion = GS.Id_Seccion
        INNER JOIN especialidad E ON E.Id_Especialidad = GS.Id_Especialidad
        INNER JOIN tipo_especialidad TE ON TE.Id_Tipo_Especialidad = E.Id_Tipo_Especialidad
        INNER JOIN alumno_grado_seccion AGS ON AGS.Id_Grado_Seccion = GS.Id_Grado_Seccion
        INNER JOIN alumno A ON A.Id_Alumno = AGS.Id_Alumno AND A.Id_Alumno = N.Id_Alumno
        INNER JOIN mes ME ON ME.Id_Mes = T.Id_Mes
        INNER JOIN periodo PE ON PE.Id_Periodo = ME.Id_Periodo
        AND N.Id_Alumno = ?
        AND YEAR(T.Fecha_Entrega) = YEAR(NOW())
        AND ME.Status = 1
        GROUP BY N.Id_Alumno, ME.Id_Mes, MG.Id_Materia_Grado
        ORDER BY A.Apellidos
```

Comment: agrega por favor la consulta que haz tratado; para que sobre esa base se te pueda apoyar

Comment: Puedes agrupar por Alumno y por Materia de este modo: `SELECT * FROM tu-tabla GROUP BY Alumno,Materia`, aunque este tipo de consultas suelen hacerse para aplicar alguna función de agregación sobre los datos como `COUNT, SUM, AVG`, etc. Lo que pasa es que tu tabla necesita un rediseño. Deberías tener una tabla aparte para las materias y enlazar mediante un identificador, en vez de tenerlas directamente en la tabla de alumnos.

Comment: @AlfredoPaz ya :) gracias